# Grouping by Result in Crystal Reports 10

Tags: crystal-reports, grouping

I am relatively new to Crystal Reports and am trying to create a report which would show me counts by group. Example:

Table "Equipment"

```
Equipment type/model Date of Repair
M                    7/12/2011
C                    3/1/2012
D                    5/9/2011
M                    10/1/2011
M                    11/1/2011
D                    9/9/2011
```

My problem is how to get the number of equipment that had 1 repair per year, 2 repairs per year, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Formula:

```
Year({Date of Repair})
```

Then group by Equipment type/model then by your new formula.

Once you've done this you can right click on the date value and select 'insert summary' and set it to count.
You can then drag the summary field to the correct group level.